# How to send Boolean value to an Insert stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to send some values to an `Insert` stored procedure, here in my code:

```
    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] parName = new string[6];
        parName[0] = "@username";
        parName[1] = "@password";
        parName[2] = "@fName";
        parName[3] = "@lName";
        parName[4] = "@gender";
        parName[5] = "@post";
        string[] parValue = new string[6];
        string gender = (rbWoman.Checked) ? "0" : "1";
        parValue[0] = txtUserName.Text;
        parValue[1] = txtPassword.Text;
        parValue[2] = txtFName.Text;
        parValue[3] = txtLName.Text;
        parValue[4] = gender;
        parValue[5] = (cb.SelectedIndex + 1).ToString();
        int affect = _clsT.Insert_Data("sp_Insert_User", parName, parValue);
        if (affect > 0)
            MessageBox.Show("ok");
        else
            MessageBox.Show(affect.ToString());
    }
```

and here is `Insert_Data` function that calls the stored procedure and send it parameters ...

```
protected int executeCommand(string query, Param[] p)
{
        try
        {
            connect();
            int affect = 0;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, _con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            int count = p.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p[i].parName, p[i].parValue);
            affect = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return affect;
        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            return ex.Number;
        }
    }
```

and finally here is stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Insert_User]
     @username varchar(20), 
     @password varchar(20),
     @fName nvarchar(20),
     @lName nvarchar(20),
     @gender bit,
     @post tinyint
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO admin(username, password, fName, lName, gender, post)
    VALUES (@username, @password, @fName, @lName, @gender, @post)
END
```

When I execute this stored procedure with these values (`j123, s123, john, smith, true, 1`), the stored procedure executes normally and affected values but when I try execute my C# code, I get a 8114 error.

So I search and found reason error that because of gender value that it's type is bool.

After that I try to send 0 or 1 instead of false or true but the error still persisting.

So could you tell me some guide to eliminate this error?

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: "After that I try to send 0 or 1 instead of false or true but the error still persisting."- try to send 'false' or 'true' now

Comment: I'm sorry for my early to judge . thanks to all but marc_s was right and I wonder that just a prefix can cause this error :|

Comment: `return ex.Number;` is the most meaninglessly evil way that you can possibly ignore errors.

Comment: SLaks what do mean  `return ex.Number;` is bad way?

Comment: Dear marc_s please write your comment as your answer i'll give it as my correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [read the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx), the CLR maps the Sql Server datatype `bit` to the C# `bool`, `Nullable<bool>` (aka `bool?`) or `SqlBoolean`.

So ...

Given a table,

```
create table dbo.foo
(
  id         int          not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered ,
  name       varchar(200) not null ,
  gender     bit              null ,
  send_email bit          not null ,
)
```

And given a stored procedure,

```
create procedure dbo.InsertFoo

  @name       varchar(200) ,
  @gender     bit ,
  @send_email bit 

as

  insert dbo.foo ( name , gender , send_email )
  values ( @name , @gender , @send_email )

go
```

You should be able to just to say the magic words:

[**Edited to note** that you have to jump through a view hoops to make the nullable bool work properly with null values. Consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds.]

```
static int InsertFoo( string name , bool? gender , bool sendEmail )
{
  int rowcount ;

  using ( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your-connect-string-here"))
  using ( SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand() )
  {

    cmd.CommandText = @"dbo.InsertFoo"                       ;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure            ;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@name"       , name      ) ;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@gender"     , gender.HasValue ? (object) gender : (object)DBNull.Value    ) ;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@send_email" , sendEmail ) ;

    conn.Open() ;
    rowcount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() ;
    conn.Close() ;

  }
  return rowcount ;
}
```

And get what you want. Here's a test case:

```
int rc1 = InsertFoo( "john"    , null  , false ) ;
int rc2 = InsertFoo( "jane"    , null  , true  ) ;
int rc3 = InsertFoo( "sally"   , false , false ) ;
int rc4 = InsertFoo( "rebecca" , false , true  ) ;
int rc5 = InsertFoo( "emily"   , true  , false ) ;
int rc6 = InsertFoo( "zoe"     , true  , true  ) ;
```

Which produces

```
id name    gender send_email
-- ------- ------ ----------
 1 john     NULL      0
 2 jane     NULL      1
 3 sally     0        0
 4 rebecca   0        1
 5 emily     1        0
 6 zoe       1        1
```

as you might expect.

Comment: nice method thanks but my problem was in SP_ prefix as marc_s's comment